# Error when statically-linking to libzbar.a: undefined reference to `_imp__GetACP@0'

Tags: c++, qt-creator, linker-errors, iconv, zbar

I link to zbar from my program. I've built zbar using mingw/msys. My application is built using Qt Creator.

When I link dynamically to zbar using `libzbar.dll.a`, it compiles and runs fine. When I link to `libzbar.a`, building my application fails with a linker error:

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libiconv.a(localcharset.o):localcharset.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `_imp__GetACP@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This convoluted path - `C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libiconv.a` - resolves to `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libiconv.a`. So it seems that Qt Creator is trying to link against its own `libiconv.a`, which is missing some functions that `libzbar.a` needs to use.

I'm not sure how to make Qt Creator use the msys `libiconv.a`, I tried this:

```
LIBS += c:/mingw/lib/libiconv.a
LIBS += $$PWD/zbar/lib/libzbar.a
```

But it had no effect, I'm getting the same error. How do I convince Qt Creator to use `c:/mingw/lib/libiconv.a` instead of its own version?

**Edit:** Here is the smallest code that reproduces the error:

```
#define NULL 0
#include <zbar.h>
int main()
{
    zbar::ImageScanner scanner;
    return 0;
}
```

And in the .pro file I have:

```
INCLUDEPATH += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
LIBS += -Lc:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib -lzbar
```

Comment: did you try with `win32:LIBS += c:/mingw/lib/libiconv.a`? or even `PRE_TARGETDEPS += c:/mingw/lib/libiconv.a`.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks for the input. I tried both but the error remains unchanged.

Comment: It would help having the project file or a fake project to reproduce the error, can you provide at least one of them?

Comment: @skypjack Here you go - I posted the smallest possible code. That's when compiling with MinGW btw.

Comment: Well, you lack at least a `TEMPLATE`, `TARGET` and `SOURCES` element. Try with something like the one I'm posting as a response, let me know if it works and I'll fix it step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a *.pro* file like the following one:

```
TEMPLATE=app
TARGET=appname
SOURCES=main.cpp
PRE_TARGETDEPS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libzbar.a
PRE_TARGETDEPS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libiconv.a
INCLUDEPATH += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
win32:LIBS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libzbar.a
win32:LIBS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libiconv.a
// ... continue
```

Comment: OMG it worked! Thanks, I'll award the bounty to you, but I it can't be awarded until 21 hours have passed.

Comment: well, do not forget it, it's my first bounty!!! I'll be back claiming soon... :-p

Comment: Reply from sashoalm: bounty=150 time=4min TTL= :-)

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to @skypjack, his solution works. I'll only add some things I found out by testing it:

`PRE_TARGETDEPS` was not really necessary, those 3 lines are sufficient to make the project compile:

```
INCLUDEPATH += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
LIBS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libzbar.a
LIBS += c:/MinGW/lib/libiconv.a
```

Which was strange because I distinctly remember trying this even before posting my question on SO. But after **swapping the last 2 lines**:

```
INCLUDEPATH += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
LIBS += c:/MinGW/lib/libiconv.a
LIBS += c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib/libzbar.a
```

the error returned. I had indeed put `libiconv.a` **before** `libzbar.a`, so the error really was because of link-order.

**Edit:** In the end, it worked even with Qt Creator's own libiconv, it was just that I needed to add it after zbar:

```
LIBS += -Lc:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib -lzbar -liconv
```